# Using script tool in python add-in wizard?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, python-script-tool, python-addin

I am trying to use a script tool in python add-in wizard to make a toolbar which will have button options. The script tool is working fine in the toolbox and I am using them in arcgis 10.2.2. The script tool I am using doesn't interact with the map. It takes in some input and run some geoprocessing. I want to add the script tool in a toolbar so that I can interact with the output of the geoprocessing. When I added it to the toolbar it does show up in the toolbar but doesn't run the script tool when clicked.

Can anyone suggest how I can use scripted tool in python add-in wizard?

Comment: Perhaps these videos will help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MIH4lP0uV3Y&list=PLFXlC8d1QyVkiOWjZ3zWDKNw8I1ZO5W5T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you've created the toolbar with the button tool via the [python add-in wizar](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/button/014p0000001z000000/)d, you can edit the python script in the Install folder and use the [`pythonaddins.GPToolDialog`](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//014p00000021000000) in the buttons `onClick` method.

Example from the [help](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//014p00000021000000):

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class OpenGPTool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        pythonaddins.GPToolDialog(r'C:\MyTools\WaterStudy.tbx', 'GroundWaterYield')
```